# What's the optimal way to use eagles?

Tags: ski-safari

When I hitch a ride with an eagle in Ski Safari, I usually try one of two things: keeping my flight horizontal, so the eagle can take me as far as possible before it poofs away; or directing it up at about a 45-degree angle, increasing my distance both vertically and horizontally, so that when the eagle poofs away I can continue to gain distance while I fall.

I'm not sure, but it feels like I don't maintain my forward momentum while falling as much as I should (or would in a real physics world..), so that's why I go for option 1 sometimes.

So: Which gets me farther? Are there other ways of using eagles that are more efficient that I haven't thought of yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the most effective way to cover a huge distance with an eagle is to fly in a wave shape. Follow the slopes downwards (watch out for rocks) and pull up at jumps.

Answer (score 1):

More distance go horizontal. More points (backflip, flame on reentry) go with option two 45 deg up.